# RNN [v2]: How to properly switch from stack to bottom tabs

Tags: react-native, wix-react-native-navigation

I'm using `setRoot()` to switch from stack navigation to bottom tab navigation and vice versa. what i noticed is every time i call `setRoot`, my components get recreated (constructor is called again, this.props shows a different roottag, etc)

Now when i listen to tab selection in my bottom tabs using `Navigation.events().registerBottomTabSelectedListener(this.tabSelectedListener)`, I receive events for each instance of the component created. I would need to listen to this to call an api and get data. if 3 instances were recreated, api will be called 3x. lodash / underscore debounce can't filter the call because its calling 3 different instances of the component/function.

Question is, is setRoot really the right way to switch from tab to stack?

Comment: I am trying to figure this out too...is there a way to unregister as a listener?

Answer (score 0):

It was indeed the listener that caused this issue. I fixed it like this:

```
let listener;

export default class YourComponent extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    listener = Navigation.events().registerBottomTabSelectedListener(({ selectedTabIndex, unselectedTabIndex }) => {this.bottomTabSelected(selectedTabIndex, unselectedTabIndex)});
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    listener.remove();
  }
...
```

[reference](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation/issues/3164#issuecomment-416519585)